# How to read data from the client socket in GUI?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have following java code. When running the program, does not appear anything. I've placed following in `main()` method.

```
try {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket sc = ss.accept();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
    String pesan = null;
    while ((pesan = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        jTextArea1.read(new FileReader(pesan), null);
    }
    br.close();
    sc.close();
    ss.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

**here is the client socket code in the below, it worked well when the server socket not on gui. i don't know how to place the server socket code on gui. what is needed, which should put the source code to work properly**

```
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

    File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    String dir = file.getAbsolutePath();

        try {

        FileReader f = new FileReader(dir);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(f);
        String b = null;
        while((b=r.readLine()) != null){
            jTextArea1.read(new FileReader(dir), null);
        }
        r.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Gagal Buka");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "IO Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: This is a server socket.

Comment: You are opening a socket and closing it again without waiting for any clients to attach. what are you trying to achieve? what is the intended purpose of the code? is there a corresponding client code? please update your question.

Comment: I've updated my question